# Using Dask with Python causes issues when running Pandas code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, out-of-memory, dask

I am trying to work with Dask because my dataframe has become large and that pandas by itself can't simply process it. I read my dataset in as follows and get the following result that looks odd, not sure why its not outputting the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dask.bag as db
import json

%matplotlib inline

Leads = db.read_text('Leads 6.4.18.txt')
Leads
```

This returns (instead of my pandas dataframe):

```
dask.bag<bag-fro..., npartitions=1>
```

Then when I try to rename a few columns:

```
Leads_updated = Leads.rename(columns={'Business Type':'Business_Type','Lender 
Type':'Lender_Type'})
Leads_updated
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Bag' object has no attribute 'rename'
```

Can someone please explain what I am not doing correctly. The ojective is to just use Dask for all these steps since it is too big for regular Python/Pandas. My understanding is the syntax used under Dask should be the same as Pandas.

Comment: A bag isn't a data-frame. Use the data-frame...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, can you please explain, not sure I follow?

Comment: You aren't using a dask data-frame, you are using a dask bag. Those are two different data-structures, and it sounds like you want the data-frame.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. Do you know why when I changed it to import dask.dataframe and then read in my csv file using dd.read_csv('Leads.csv') it outputs a dafaframe with 1 row that is all labeled as datatypes like object, float64, rather then actual values like in pandas?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read through the dask documentation and understand what's going on. There's also some decent tutorials around the web, e.g. https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/blob/master/04_dataframe.ipynb

Comment: Thank you. So do I understand correctly, looking at the link you provided that dask only helps import an originally large csv file, as opposed to better process dataframes you already have created in the middle of your python code after an import? So if my original dataframe was not large, but another one became large as part of my code, dask would not help in this scenario, unless I export it to a csv file and import it back in?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "help with", but if your data fits nicely into memory, there is a good chance that pandas is perfectly good for processing it.

Comment: my dataset works perfectly fine when it has roughly 200 variables. I dummified my feature "City" which brought it 22,000 dimensional space and when I tried filtering on this new dataframe column using regular pandas loc\.iloc, and it gives me a MemoryError. That's why I have been looking into Dask

Comment: do you mind to share an example of your dataframe? Are you sure that is `,`separated and not `;` separated?

Comment: you mean separating the columns? Yep, pretty much like I posted it.